# some confusions about lambda function/closure in Golang

Tags: go, lambda, closures

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
)
func main(){
    f,val,val1:=fibonacci()
    fmt.Println(val,val1)
    for i:=0;i<=10;i++ {
        fmt.Println(f(i),val,val1)
    }
    _,val,val1=fibonacci()
    fmt.Println(val,val1)
}
func fibonacci()(func(n int)int,int,int){
    var val int
    var val1 int
    f:=func(n int)int{
        if n==0||n==1{
            val,val1=1,1
        }else{
            val,val1=val+val1,val
        }
        return val
    }
    fmt.Println("fibonacci val =",val,"val1 =",val1)
    return f,val,val1
}
```

> Here is my code on sloving fibonacci without using recursion when I
>   read about lambda function/closure. And the Go Documentary says a
>   closure will  capture some external state. My understanding is the
>   closure will keep a  copy of state of the function which it is
>   declared. These states are just  copies whatever I do on them won't
>   modify the original, is that so?

Comment: no, it will modify the original too.

Comment: but,check this.

Comment: huh,I set val and val1 as return values, then print them,their values are always 0, why?

Comment: could you show me your test code?
https://play.golang.org/p/EbH2dMCAeC
see this to see how outer value changed by closure.

Comment: My code is above.

Comment: 1、the print in for loop is all zero, because the val and val1 return from first call `fibonacci` is a copy from the variable in `fibonacci` function, so they are not be modify.
2、the second call to `fibonacci` will create a new closure and a new val and val1 different from first call. so it will print zero also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from your test code here: https://play.golang.org/p/pajT2bAIe2

your fibonacci function is working out the nth numbers in the sequence provided it's called in an incremental fashion as you are doing. but the values you return from the initial call to `fibonacci` are not pointers (or references) to those integer values they are just the values of those integers at that time, think of them as being copied out of the function, try using integer pointers instead like this: https://play.golang.org/p/-vLja7Fpsq

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    f, val, val1 := fibonacci()
    fmt.Println(val, val1)
    for i := 0; i <= 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println(f(i), *val, *val1) //dereference the pointer to get its value at the current time
    }
    _, val, val1 = fibonacci()
    fmt.Println(*val, *val1)
}
func fibonacci() (func(n int) int, *int, *int) {
    var val int
    var val1 int
    f := func(n int) int {
        if n == 0 || n == 1 {
            val, val1 = 1, 1
        } else {
            val, val1 = val+val1, val
        }
        return val
    }
    fmt.Println("fibonacci val =", val, "val1 =", val1)
    return f, &val, &val1 // return pointers to the closured values instead of just the values
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you have accepted the above answer i'm giving another explanation. The reason why you receive the last value of the loop operation has to do with the `Go`'s  lexical scoping. The `for loop` introduces a new lexical block in which the value is referenced by it's memory address, so by pointer and not by it's value. In order to get the value, you have to de-reference.

Each time the for loop makes an iteration the value processed is pointing to the same memory address. All the function values created by this loop "capture" and share the **same** variable - and addressable storage location, not it's value at that particular moment. Thus when the last iteration is finished, the variable holds the value from the final step.

A much better approach for these kind of operations would be to use goroutines, because in these cases you are not communicating through sharing the same memory address, but you are sharing the memory through communication.

Here is a more elegant solution using goroutine:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func fibonacci(ch chan interface{}, quit chan struct{}) {
    x, y := 1, 1
    for {
        select {
        case ch <- x:
            x, y = y, x+y
            fmt.Println(x , y)
        case <-quit:
            fmt.Println("Quiting...")
            return
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan interface{})
    quit := make(chan struct{})

    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            <-ch
        }
        quit <- struct{}{}
    }()

    fibonacci(ch, quit)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/oPQgXWyV9u